# React warning uncontrolled component in child component

Tags: reactjs, rendering, parent-child

I have child form and input components that are rendered within a parent project component. In the parent component, they are "uncontrolled" as in their value isn't initially set by the parent project's state. Their value is set by the form component state immediately. React keeps giving me this "Warning" (which registers as an error in the console).

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
```

I understand the issue with controlled vs non controlled components. But how do I get React to see that the child is controlling the input rather than the parent and stop giving me this error?

Other relevant info: this is an external forms module that I created because my apps use a lot of forms and I wanted a standardized way to  implement this with just an "npm install ...". This is the sudo code

```
    <Parent project module>
    //external forms components
    <Form>
    <Input/>
    <Input/>
    <Button/>
    </Form>
    //end external forms components
    </Parent project module>
```

Here is the render method in the Form component that allows me to control the Input state from withing the Form component. Please let me know if other code snippets or other info would be helpful. Am I going about this incorrectly or is there some way to get rid of these errors? Everything works fine, but it clutters my console and makes it difficult to code.

```
render() {
    const inputs = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
            value: this.state.value,
            onChange: this.onChange,
            error: this.state.userNotify[child.props.name]
        })
    );

    return (
        <div id="form-container">
            <p className="formTitle">{this.props.formTitle}</p>
            <form id={this.props.formID} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                {inputs} {/*there must be nested input components passed in*/}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try assigning a fallback value to your input components when their state value is not set yet.

```
const inputs = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, {
    value: this.state.value || '',
    onChange: this.onChange,
    error: this.state.userNotify[child.props.name]
  })
);
```

This ensures that the value will never be `undefined` or `null` thus removing those console warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having value intialized in state

Like in constructor

```
      this.state = {
           value: null
      }
```

Or on class level

```
     state = {
           value: null
      }
```

So change value: null to value: ""

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your suggestions. While they were not solutions in this case, they helped me to think through and identify the problem.

I have a prop on the Input component called prepPopVal. I use it to pre-populate the input with some value. For example; when viewing existing data, you can use my Form/Input component to display that data. It looks like this in the parent project

```
<Parent project module>
//external forms components
<Form>
<Input prePopVal={this.state.someValue}/>
<Button/>
</Form>
//end external forms components
</Parent project module>
```

I was using a conditional like this

```
 if(typeof this.props.prePopVal === 'undefined')
      var value = this.props.value;
    else
      var value = this.props.prePopVal;
```

then placing the "value" variable as the value of the html input

```
   <input className="textinput"
          type={type}
          id={this.props.name}
          name={this.props.name}
          value={value}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          autoComplete="off"
        />
```

What I should have done is eliminated the conditional logic to set "value" and just used the "||" operator within the input to decide which to use, like this:

```
<input className="textinput"
      type={type}
      id={this.props.name}
      name={this.props.name}
      value={this.props.prePopVal || this.props.value}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      autoComplete="off"
    />
```

This way if "prePopVal" isn't defined it uses "value". This cleared my console error.

Thanks again. I hope this question is useful to someone.